# How to create custom template and apply at a run time in asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating web application in vs2012 where admin can create custom template means admin can create custom master pages at a run time & that should be applied to all pages. Second thing after creating master page he must be able to change contentplaceholder positions too. How does it possible? any open source tool or coding functionality? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use ASP.NET MVC 4 is a framework for building scalable, standards-based web applications using well-established design patterns and the power..
http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to allow the admin to edit the template directly. That could be dangerous though because they could make a typo that would crash the site, or inject some naughty code, etc. A safer option would be to use something like [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine). As far as changing the content placeholder positions, that is a little more complicated and depends on how you build out the templating system.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Actually, I'm lil more talking about CMS(Content management system) kind of tool. But, its client requirement & the work is on high priority.

Comment: If you're looking for an asp.net based CMS I would try Orchard - http://www.orchardproject.net/